# Update one row with other row data from same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with 90 columns and and I want to update/insert the Null columns with the value from the most preceding record for that particular group.

***For example :*** I have to update null columns for *ID = 8* with all the non null values from the preceding record ( ID_PK Ascending order ).If preceding record is null then the next preceding record and so on.

Similarly for  *Grp2* , update the record where the *ID = 15* with that group preceding records and so on...

The trouble is I've approx 90 columns to check and update.Is there any special way rather than singling out each column and checking the previous records value.

Thanks for looking at the question.

Below is subset of that table

```
   Group   ID_PK  TAX   REASON     DT      TYPE   FLG
  =====  ======  ====  =======  =======    ====   ===

   Grp1     2              1     6/30/2013  SD     N
   Grp1     3     18813    1                MEM      
   Grp1     5              1                SDHC   N
   Grp1     8                               NOR 

   Grp2     9     12713    3     5/20/2014  SDHC   Y
   Grp2     11                              NOR    N
   Grp2     15    12713
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an oracle database instance to confirm 100% that this works, but the function that you are likely looking for is lag()

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm

The issue for you is going to be that you need to have lag go back a different number of rows, depending on how many records are needed to traverse before a null value. You could write a really long CASE statement that would work, but be sub-optimal.  But, lag() is going to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Yeah I can try using lag or some dynamic SQL to parse through each column and each row.But I was thinking if there is a way to compare not null values across a set of rows in that group. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date, salary,
LAG(salary, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY hire_date) AS prev_sal
FROM employees
WHERE job_id = 'PU_CLERK';

LAST_NAME                 HIRE_DATE     SALARY   PREV_SAL
------------------------- --------- ---------- ----------
Khoo                      18-MAY-95       3100          0
Tobias                    24-JUL-97       2800       3100
Baida                     24-DEC-97       2900       2800
Himuro                    15-NOV-98       2600       2900
Colmenares                10-AUG-99       2500       2600
```

LAG is an analytic function. It provides access to more than one row of a table at the same time without a self join. Given a series of rows returned from a query and a position of the cursor, LAG provides access to a row at a given physical offset prior to that position.

Comment: thanks for the information.I will try to incorporate this in dynamic sql

Comment: vote so everyone knows which ans helped you thank you.